# How to preview pdf file before download using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I created pdf file generator using jsPDF library .It's work fine Pdf file nicely downloading .But I need preview that pdf file before downloading

Here my Code

```
 const doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text('hello world');
doc.save('test.pdf');
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library called [`filepreview`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filepreview) that:

> Will generate a file preview (gif, jpg or png) of about 450 different document formats.

That includes PDF. It seems quite heavy-weight (because of all the formats it supports), but looks like it will do exactly what is required:

var filepreview = require('filepreview');

```
filepreview.generate('test.pdf', 'test_preview.png', function(error) {
  if (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  }
  console.log('File preview is test_preview.png');
});
```